# Do filesystems store time zone information?

Tags: python, timezone

Do filesystems store time zone information along with the file information? I ran into a weird bug where I do the following snippet and I get different time zone printed out.

```
import DateTime #zope's module
for each in os.listdir("director"):
    print DateTime.DateTime(os.stat(each)[8])

#Why is it mixed up?
Foo 12:00:00 US/Eastern
Bar 12:00:00 GMT -4
```

It started to happen after Daylight Saving changes were made. I see Eastern and GMT -4 both. IIRC Linux doesn't store the time stamp information, instead it stores time as absolute seconds elapsed from Jan 1st 1970.

Is it possible that some file systems store time zone information? I was informed that DST (Daylight Saving Time) is expressed by using different timezones. So in day light saving scenario or in general - are these meta data's stored by file-system?

For eg: https://rsync.samba.org/daylight-savings.htm points out that FAT stores Daylight Saving Information.

Since as per the accepted answer both are same time zones, is it possible to show GMT -4 as Eastern Daylight Savings Time to make things really clear to the end user?

Comment: Are you sure it's not the `DateTime` constructor introducing the time zone information?

Comment: I see mixed results - some files are GMT -4 and some are US/Eastern - if it was the constructor doing that then it it has to be either Eastern or GMT right?

Comment: Also, the link you gave doesn't actually say FAT stores DST info; it says FAT stores timestamps in local time.

Comment: The Zope DateTime docs say a call with no time zone specified will use the machine's time zone. I'm not sure how that interacts with DST, but if the machine's time zone changes between calls, you'd see different time zones in the output.

Comment: Thanks. For the folder I loop, I get different time zone for different file (Either GMT -4 or US/Eastern). So it doesn't change between calls, however I will see if I can enforce a time zone during call if that prevents the issue from happening.

Comment: This is just a guess, but there's probably something in Zope that incorrectly assumes that GMT-5 == US/Eastern.  See "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Comment: GMT -5 is US/Eastern right ? GMT -4 being US/Eastern Daylight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any file system that store timezone information with their timestamps. Depending on the file system / operating system it's either stored in UTC, or in the local time.

Zope's DateTime will use your local timezone unless you specify something else.

US/Estern is GMT -4 during daylight savings, so this is probably correct.

Comment: But how would you explain a folder being looped over showing up files with both US/Eastern and GMT -4 - mixed? I can think of a global setting used by Zope's DateTime which would show up as either US/Eastern or GMT -4 but not a mixed result set.

Comment: US/Eastern during daylight savings is GMT-4. Hence, it is not a mixed set.

Comment: I mean I see some files showing up as US/Eastern and some as GMT -4 in the same folder. Something like for each in os.listdir(dir): print DateTime(os.stat(each)[8])

Comment: I understand what you say. Look at the dates. Note that all that are marked as GMT-4 are during daylight savings time (ie summer) and the others are not. It's the same timezone.

If you don't understand, then please explain what you don't understand instead of just repeating the question. It is NOT a mixed set.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. You mean that DateTime converts a UTC Time to UTC - 4 and shows it up as GMT -4 using its own "if it was added in summer logic"  to distinguish that it was summer time - while for the rest it does UTC - 5 and shows it as US/Eastern. It could also have been shown as GMT -4 as EDT right? Further if I want to show it up as EST regardless, I should perhaps subtract 1 hour and show it up? If that doesn't make sense thats fine. I will just read up further.

Comment: It should not show up as EST regardless, it's not EST. And I don't see why you should add anything to it. Are the times *wrong*?

Comment: We might want to move this to chat, btw.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77323/discussion-between-nishant-and-lennart-regebro).