# How to get/set modification times in cross platform way from a (bash) script?

Tags: linux, macos, bash, stat

I use a combination of `stat` and `touch` for getting/setting timestamps on files and repertories. But I need different set-ups if on mac os x or GNU/Linux:

1. `touch` on mac os x does not know the `-d` option described there

   http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/touch.html

   which allows things like

   ```
   touch -d "2007-11-12 10:15:30.002Z" ajosey
   ```

   I am seemingly constrained to `-t [[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.SS]`.
2. `stat` also differs, for example on a Linux account of mine, it does not recognize the `-t format` from the `stat` on mac os x.

Thus on the Linux I currently do something like

```
stat --format 'touch -d "%y" "%n"' index.html
```

to create a command line of the type

```
touch -d "2015-04-08 00:38:51.940365000 +0200" "index.html"
```

whereas on the mac os x I have

```
stat -f "touch -t %Sm \"%N\"" -t %Y%m%d%H%M.%S index.html
```

which gives me something (this is not the same `index.html` as prior) like:

```
touch -t 201503281339.42 "index.html"
```

How could handle this in a unified way ? Perhaps with some `sed` in between ?

I need to produce a sequence of `touch` commands in a format working on both platforms. The creation of this sequence must work on both platforms.

I am open to other scripting than bash, with the constraint that on the Linux side I am with a system with no admin rights. `perl` there is `This is perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi`.

Comment: I think you just need to write a conditional/switch on `uname -o`? (`if [ $(uname -o) == linux ];then `....)

Comment: You can drop the time zone. It will not be written into the file system: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30119732/do-filesystems-store-time-zone-information

Comment: @JeffY I was hoping for code common to GNU/Linux like Ubuntu and Mac OS X ... keeping the conditional as a last resort. And even if usingv conditionals I need to be able to create on the Linux a sequence of commands suitable for Mac OS, and vice versa.

Comment: @ceving ok, thanks for the link, but it doesn't hurt either.

Comment: @jfbu It hurts in that way, that it is one item on the list of incompatibilities: "I am seemingly constrained to `-t [[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.SS]`".

Comment: @ceving and that would be for the local time you are right. Which means I need a way if some utility returns a time to either query it without time zone or convert it to local time. The touch on mac os x accepts -A to apply an additional shift, for example `-A 010000` for reducing by one hour.

Comment: Use `python` instead?

Comment: @trojanfoe will think about it, I trust `perl` would do also, but still have to learn it.

Comment: I expect so, but it's a horrible syntax...

Comment: @JeffY `-o` is illegal option for `uname` on mac os x. Would be more like `uname -s`: `-s      print the operating system name.`, which in practice returns `Darwin`. On my Linux, `uname -s` outputs `Linux`.

Comment: @JeffY I have provided a self-answer based on a conditional switch.

Answer (score 1):

Short of a better method, I will temporarily adopt the following, which is based on these observations:

1. `touch -t` works the same on my mac os x and the Linux I have access too.
2. On the Linux side, I can use `date -d` to transform a date as produced by `stat -c %y` to the `YYYYMMDDHHMM.SS` format I can use on input to `touch -t`, and on the Mac OS X side I can use directly `stat` with suitable options for this result.

For batch processing of files in a repertory, where I was using `stat` with `*` shell expansion, I can replace that with a `for` shell loop.

Putting these things together I end with the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                       
case `uname -s` in
    "Linux" )
        MYDATEFORTOUCH() {
            date -d"$(stat -c %y "$1")" +%Y%m%d%H%M.%S
        }
        ;;
    "Darwin" )
        MYDATEFORTOUCH() {
            stat -f %Sm -t %Y%m%d%H%M.%S "$1"
        }
        ;;
    * )
        MYDATEFORTOUCH() {
            197001010000.00
        }
        ;;
esac

echo "#!/bin/sh" > fichierTEMPA

for file in *
do echo "touch -ch -t $(MYDATEFORTOUCH "$file") \"$file\"" >> fichierTEMPA
done
```

Executing this in a repertory produces a file (with silly name here `fichierTEMPA`) which is a series of `touch -t` commands. The `-h` is for not following symbolic links, on mac os x, it implies the `-c` which is to not create a file which didn't exist, I am not sure if `-c` is also implied by `-h` on GNU/Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Install the [GNU Coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html) on your Mac and you can stop bothering about incompatibilities. It is explained [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/69223/100446) how to do it.